# regEx for a range of 8600000–9999999?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking for a way to validate a phone number with the length of 7, and within the rage of 8600000–9999999 (This is a region in New Zealand, witch is why google was no help as no one talks about New Zealand -- ever). Does anyone know a regEx that can do this?

I'm new to JS, but I think that a Regular Expression would be the best way to do this. (If not let me know.)

Note: The input data type of the phone number is text. (I know I can use number but I ran into bugs with it.)

EDIT -- no lines / separation, just numbers. (Also very fast answers just wow)

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Should be trivial. Are the numbers separated by anything?

Comment: `I know I can use number but I ran into bugs with it.` You can simply ask here about these "bugs". As for me, you don't need Regex here. I would simply use numbers.

Comment: How about `x > 8600000 && x < 9999999`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one's actually pretty easy:

```
/8[6-9][0-9]{5}|9[0-9]{6}/
```

As long as you don't need separators, anyways.

It's also pretty simple to follow:

- `8` matches the literal character 8.
- `[6-9]` matches any single character that is in the ASCII range between the characters 6 and 9 (inclusive). This means that it will match any single 6, 7, 8, or 9.
- Likewise, `[0-9]` matches any single character that is in the ASCII range betwen the characters 0 and 9. This is synonymous with "any single digit".
- `{5}` means "match the preceding token 5 times". In this case, it's applied to `[0-9]`, meaning it'll match 5 digits in a row.
- The `|` (pipe) character in a regex is an alternation - it means "match either the pattern on the right or the left". This is how the regex handles the two different cases - 8600000-8999999 is handled by the pattern on the left, while 9000000-9999999 is handled by the pattern on the right.

Comment: It will not match 9200000, for example

Comment: \d matches unicode digits outside 0-9. (e.g. `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`) I think he wants 0-9 specifically.

Comment: I have addressed all complaints.

Comment: @TylerY86 I don't think JS does unicode regular expressions

Comment: @Phil Yeah, you're right, `\d` works fine. Just pendantics.

Comment: For anyone curious, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp there's the /u flag to opt-in, not supported cross browser (see bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode)

Comment: Thanks! Could you brake down what you did for a noob to understand? If you don't mind.

Comment: @Draxy: Added a quick breakdown of the regex.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the regular expression [**`/(?:9[0-9]|8[6-9])[0-9]{5}/`**](https://regex101.com/r/nA4xL4/1).
You can [click](https://regex101.com/r/nA4xL4/1) to play with it on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), and see some test cases.

Here's the breakdown (provided by [regex101.com](https://regex101.com)):

- `(?:9[0-9]|8[6-9])` Non-capturing group

  - 1st Alternative: `9[0-9]`, left of `|`

    - `9` matches the character 9 literally
    - `[0-9]` match a single character present in the list below

      - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - 2nd Alternative: `8[6-9]`, right of `|`

    - `8` matches the character 8 literally
    - `[6-9]` match a single character present in the list below

      - `6-9` a single character in the range between 6 and 9
- `[0-9]{5}` match a single character present in the list below

  - `0-9` a single character in the range between 0 and 9
  - `{5}` exactly 5 times

Comment: It will not match 9200000

Comment: Updating expression to match ...